# LibreOffice Writer: minimize, cross and enlarge buttons are missing

Tags: 14.04

I have just installed Ubuntu version 14.04, its unfortunate the libre office doesn’t show the buttons for minimising, closing and enlargement of the libre office. Would anyone help me to sort out.

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug that sometimes puts the LibreOffice window too high on the screen and the top bar is unreachable.

Try to press the ALT key, click anywhere on the Libreoffice window whit the mouse and move it while keeping the left button pressed. The window should move and you should be able to see the top bar.

Now resize the windows to something you like and close it. It should remember its position and size the next time that you open it.